# Typescript subset of enum

Tags: typescript, enums

In Typescript, I have an enum like

```
export enum CarBrands {
   Toyota = "TOYOTA"
   Ford = "FORD"
   .....
}
```

I would like to create a subset of this enum like this but cannot seem to do it

```
enum JapaneseCars {
    CarBrands.Toyota
}
```

or create an object with a subset

```
const JapaneseCars = {
    Carbrands.Toyota
}
```

Is there anyway i can create an object or enum that uses that values from another existing enum?

I cannot change the CarBrands enum to be some other data type

Comment: gatsbyz's answer is the best one

Answer (score 25):

You can create a `type` and `const` combination that will behave like an enum that is the subset of another enum.

**Drawback: this solution forces you to have any `enum`'s key match their value** (or I have not found a solution that handles that case yet)

```
// Given an enum
export enum CarBrand {
  TOYOTA = 'TOYOTA',
  FORD = 'FORD',
  PEUGEOT = 'PEUGEOT',
  RENAULT = 'RENAULT'
}

// We can create the type of the subset
export type FrenchCarBrand = Extract<CarBrand, CarBrand.PEUGEOT | CarBrand.RENAULT>;

// And the const that goes with it
export const FrenchCarBrand = {
  [CarBrand.PEUGEOT]: CarBrand.PEUGEOT,
  [CarBrand.RENAULT]: CarBrand.RENAULT
} as const;

// With that you can :

// assign a CarBrand to a FrenchCarBrand ...
const a: FrenchCarBrand = CarBrand.RENAULT;

// ... as long as the CarBrand is in the type
const a_invalid: FrenchCarBrand = CarBrand.TOYOTA; // Type 'CarBrand.TOYOTA' is not assignable to type 'FrenchCarBrand'.

// assign a FrenchCarBrand to a CarBrand ...
const b: CarBrand = FrenchCarBrand.PEUGEOT;

// ... as long as the key exists
const b_invalid: CarBrand = FrenchCarBrand.TOYOTA; // Property 'TOYOTA' does not exist on type 'Readonly<Record<FrenchCarBrand, FrenchCarBrand>>'

// You cannot reassign the value of a FrenchCarBrand ...
FrenchCarBrand.PEUGEOT = CarBrand.RENAULT; // Cannot assign to 'PEUGEOT' because it is a read-only property.

// ... just like you cannot reassign the value of an enum
CarBrand.TOYOTA = 'MAZDA'; // Cannot assign to 'TOYOTA' because it is a read-only property.
```

If you want to map an unknown value of type `CarBrand` to a value of type `FrenchCarBrand`, it will not work though :

```
declare const brand: CarBrand;
const frenchBrand: FrenchCarBrand = brand; // Type 'CarBrand' is not assignable to type 'FrenchCarBrand'

// You can use the `as` keyword but it will hide bugs, so I do not recommend at all.
const frenchBrandNoError: FrenchCarBrand = brand as FrenchCarBrand; // No error, but a possible bug in your application.
```

For that you need a type guard :

```
export const isFrenchCarBrand = (brand: CarBrand): brand is FrenchCarBrand => {
  return brand in FrenchCarBrand;
}
```

It will allow you to decide what to do in case you encounter an unwanted value

```
if (isFrenchCarBrand(brand)) {
  // You can safely assume that `brand` is a `FrenchCarBrand`
} else {
  // `brand` is definitely not a `FrenchCarBrand`
}
```

I have made a [TypeScript Playground that show all this code with type checking in action](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHEEsDcFMDtQENEIK4FsBQsAeAHAewCcAXUdDUAYSWICFiUATUAby1FABUB5ATV7cAgqAC8oAOR9BIyQBpOoAGK8ASgBFxU1ZoVKACgFEAquCNDtk42Yvd9XNUYBywkwBluVp64-2sAL5YWCCgAOqwoADGKNHEsEikkaQAFskAnviRhABmoKmRAM5oAEaFsKQ4BCTkpJmRyvHwUSm0DEzwrBJGuKRMUaQAPG2MLPI0dKOdAHQ25pYAPhPtLNM+bp4AfADcwaHCnflp0YTwhbUpiaAA5oSwhaAA7pCpoC9VRGQnZ+SNCC0jDpddhKADagNWczsAF0AFzLKbMWamebcRRccGTIFrFwbbhwhHY9Z+QLIB5RU7nXYhMBhF4pI5XdKENDRWKwvZgJCFQqQa6IJCElj5QjIFRNAFY4XTGVYCk-ZDwv7NVpSw4SCEzYmeamhGXTMmgAA2p2uhoKQsOkAekEQFrqWTllPISAA+rboEgjZBmEqJaqVurLUiZEJhNtQKFuPUpJqQwIw5I3g94IQXTy+fAkCUjclRQ7IpJlZLA8xJNNOWTefyxcWA4iRWK46B9U6FSV4c2JHW48jbEJdWB9YaTfAzdyjpEANawdIUXDW0iFNvnUAld3wT3e33B7Q9tXx2ThyNgAzEQhZMhz6QJuSgZh3FNp+eL0CnfIxyRqBIP+BG9KDN+FLEMwgz7qW4zgYimybJIlb8CybLwKm5DxNy1Z2scW5oNkeSClBQItrKBGQiidjaL22rcBGoS0Mhz7oZmjbWGRQhJiUsAxGg5RvOQ1pimhzAALSnP+oD4Oel51BWWDMJxRp0JE8qriUQKdgeuzKeQOT+oifr-PWhESKpLA0WA0ZZLGB5JvxKFVpm2a5o2BY6P6cZwTSoAIayMSINxyTHAABtygWgDO6SPCQrAlGgfHkM8RpGqAKQ+pEMXXIU4yFKKACS96inZ8QUhgGAIKwVxekaFZaaAOkGYiziEEYxDnsQ+kql2a6EROJGdGZoCNRQLUkOMMUuuJhAZjmaVoGatqgMyaDEMg+D4N6MSkJApwyXgnzkDV1q9cCAAUJmdOppYAJTwmdrD8Ud4ibCCXDxKQS2ILdbyIEduxBFgkB5Mdh1uQep1Apdl3PSeXmIb5oCFEgOSwGJ6GYAFVyBbdoX8YKgXKswcaBUot2-RQRo8RwXChJjQLYw8ck5LaLzI3Odm4-jhPE0Cv1YEAA)

Comment: Why is the "export const FrenchCarBrand..." required?

Comment: We have to have a `const FrenchCarBrand` so that the generated JS has a `FrenchCarBrand` object that you can use like `FrenchCarBrand.PEUGEOT`.
If you don't have the const, you get an error `'FrenchCarBrand' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` when you try to use `FrenchCarBrand.PEUGEOT`.

Comment: for that extracted I'm getting
TS2693: 'ButtonTypes' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. from: **export type ButtonTypes = Extract<ColorVariant, ColorVariant.PRIMARY>;**

Comment: While this is pretty good, I'm still missing the options being narrowed when assigning to a `FrenchCarBrand` since I can choose between all options in the enum. Yes if I assign it to a wrong one I get an error but there\s not reason I should be able to even see it. Is it possible?

Comment: @NiclasGleesborg I am afraid this may be related to the code editor used; I think in theory the editor would be able to know with value is available, but the use case may prove to be a bit complicated to implement ?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for something like this -

```
export enum CarBrands {
  Toyota = "TOYOTA",
  Ford = "FORD"
}

type JapaneseCars = CarBrands.Toyota;

const car: JapaneseCars;
```

Comment: I can't get why this answer has lowest score. It's the most straightforward actually. In case someone without TypeScript knowledge didn't get it, `JapaneseCars` can have several possible values: `type JapaneseCars = CarBrands.Toyota | CarBrands.Nissan;`

Comment: @Mikhail Batcer enum is supposed to create real value. Here you create a type while the question was about enum being a subset of another enum.

Comment: Object.values(JapaneseCars) // type doesn't work like an enum

Answer (score 3):

One possible workaround, that doesn't require creating a constant with Enum keys equal to their values, could be to use [Extract<Type, Union>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to create a type with desired Enum values.

Of course, it won't go as far as creating a new Enum but you will be able to type constants or properties and it will ensure typings for extracted values from the original Enum.

```js
enum CarBrands {
  Chevrolet = 'CHEVROLET',
  Honda = 'HONDA',
  Toyota = 'TOYOTA',
  Ford = 'FORD',
  // etc...
}

type JapaneseBrands = Extract<
  CarBrands,
  | CarBrands.Honda
  | CarBrands.Toyota
  // etc...
>;

const goodJapaneseBrands: JapaneseBrands = CarBrands.Honda; // OK
const badJapaneseBrands: JapaneseBrands = CarBrands.Ford; // ERROR
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to make an indexed object with optional values:

```
enum CarBrand {
  TOYOTA = "TOYOTA",
  FORD = "FORD"
}

type CarsSubset = {
  [key in CarBrand]?: boolean
}

const JapaneseCars: CarsSubset  = {
  TOYOTA: true,
}
```

For this particular example it may be clearer to just use `Set<CarBrand>` though:

```
const JapaneseCars = new Set<CarBrand>([CarBrand.TOYOTA]);
```

Answer (score -2):

You could make a variable for every single enum member, which would be tedious if you have a lot of enum members but it would look like this.

```
export enum CarBrands {
    Toyota = "TOYOTA",
    Ford = "FORD"
}

const Toyota = CarBrands.Toyota;
console.log("The Supra is made by", Toyota)
```

or you can use a simple method

```
class JapaneseCar {
    make: string;
    // Additional Methods / Properties

    setMake(brand:CarBrands){
        this.make = brand;
    }
}

const ToyotaSupra = new JapaneseCar();
ToyotaSupra.setMake(CarBrands.Toyota);
console.log(ToyotaSupra.make)
```